# Display progress bar beside the text in ListView

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I'm trying to make a listView with progress bar exactly like the image below

[image]

I'm use  `android:layout_toRightOf` to display the progressBar beside the `Pro-XXX-XXX`, but it display below the text .

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListProject"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListProject" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Change to RelativeLayout**

[image]

@Chintan answer

[image]

Comment: So what is your problem in doing this ?

Comment: @Sree I want the progress bar display beside the Pro-XXX

Comment: Try changing LinearLayout to Relative layout.

Comment: you have a lot methods to do this, try your self all the very best

Comment: @TdSoft check my post again.Thanks

Comment: Check my answer hope that is helpful for you.

Comment: @ChintanBawa Yor answer look better but Pro-XXX-XXX cannot display fully

Comment: thats because your text is larger than your TextView size. Just make the TextView double lined an please accept and upvote the answer if its helpful. @Seng

Comment: @ChintanBawa How to make it double line ? Can you please help me ? Many thanks.

Comment: Add  this  android:lines="2" in your TextView. I also edited my answer. Please check. @Seng

Comment: There is no need to make it "double line" ... That is just moulding it to work and not solving the problem. You want your text in line with the progress bar, simply add "toRightOf and "toEndOf" .. Check my answer please. It will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the tools provided with the Relative Layout.

Your ProgressBar needs to be "toRightOf" as well as "toEndOf" the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListProject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ListProject"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListProject"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have just tested this xml, and it works perfectly well.

Comment: Thanks, your code works well. Do you know how to customize the progress bar so that it will look like the image I posted or make the size bigger? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept as answer if it worked. The progress bar question is not relevant to this layout question. Please post a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

put following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListProject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HProxx -cxcscdc"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HProxx -cxcscdc"
        android:textColor="#CADFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:text="HProxx -cxcscdc"
        android:textColor="#CADFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HProxx -cxcscdc"
        android:textColor="#CADFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your output same with @Chintan

Answer (score -1):

Replace your `xml` with `xml` below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListProject"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you.